# хоткей для дублировать выделенный код или текущую строку 1С

Tags: 1с

кто знает какой горячей клавишей в редакторе кода 1С можно дублировать выделенный код или текущую строку?

типа Ctrl+D в VisualStudio и в Android studio и в Intellij idea и в VScode.

Answer (score 1):

Без сторонних инструментов - никак. Пользуюсь [Turboconf](https://turboconf.ru), там есть такая возможность.